# Create loop with parameters for list of items (add in items as you go)

Tags: python, list, loops, pandas

I have a a list of items (1-11 in this case, but it could be longer) and each item has a set of 8 coordinates (x,y,z). I am trying to build up a group of coordinates that fit a parameter distance.

To do this, I want to use the distance formula to calculate the distance between each set of coordinates (x1,y1,z1) *from item 1* and each set *from item 2* (x2,y2,z2) - 8 sets of coordinates for each item means 64 distances calculated.

If this distance fits a parameter (say, 1 < d < 2), then calculate the distance between the first set and the third set (x3,y3,z3) and the second set and the third set.  This time, there will be 128 distances calculated.  This idea is proving to be very advanced for my beginner knowledge.  I have started with the following code

```
from itertools import product
import math
import pandas as pd
import csv
subset = cmd[['carbon','x_coord', 'y_coord','z_coord']]
pos_coordinate_values = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
list1 = []
for t in list1:
   row = ""
   rowNum = t[0]
   x1 = t[1]
   y1 = t[2]
   z1 = t[3]

   def calculate_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2,z1,z2):
      dist=math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2-z1)**2)
      return dist
   d=calculate_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2,z1,z2)

   if t[0] in list1:
       if rowNum == 1 and rowNum == 2:
           return d
       if d >= 1 and d <= 2:
           if rowNum == 1 and rowNum == 2 and rowNum == 3:
               return d
```

Desired output would be a list of coordinates from each item that made it through all of the parameters.

```
Viable strings are;
(1, (2, 3, 2), 2, (2, 4, 2), 3, (2, 5, 3), 4, (2, 6, 4), 5, (2, 8, 2), 6, (3, 4, 2), 7, (3, 5, 3), 8, (3, 6, 4), 9, (3, 8, 2), 10, (4, 5, 3), 11, (4, 6, 4))
(1, (5, 7, 3), 2, (5, 1, 4), 3, (5, 1, 3), 4, (5, 3, 4), 5, (7, 8, 4), 6, (7, 9, 4), 7, (7, 1, 3), 8, (7, 1, 2), 9, (7, 3, 3), 10, (8, 1, 4), 11, (9, 1, 4))
...
```

(these were randomly generated) Where the first number is it item followed by its coordinate set that fit all of the parameters.

I am aware that my code is very wrong.  Unfortunately, I do not have the knowledge for how to frame this code to get the desired output. I am an avid learner and this code would greatly speed up my data analysis.  Help or simple suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
The code you posted doesn't even pass a syntax check: you have a **return** in your main program.

Comment: Also, please describe the problem you are trying to solve. It is likely that someone knows a better approach to the actual problem, rather than how to get this particular computation working.

Comment: Looks like you have an interesting problem buried in this question.  I've even got ideas on things to try.  But I feel like giving it a go is going to be a waste of time because chances are, it will be an incorrect guess at what you want.  Believe it or not, it takes time and energy to answer these questions.  Others may feel as I do, and don't want to invest their time into something that won't answer your question and won't get them any points.  I  say this to encourage you to improve your question so that you motivate people to respond and maximize your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Also, I notice you have a lot of questions in which you haven't accepted an answer.  If those questions have been answered, go make some posters happy and select an answer.  And upvote those accepted answers, as well as some of the other good answers.  Taking the time to do that and showing some gratitude for the work that people have put into answering your questions will go a long way towards encouraging people to continue answering your questions.